# boost static library link failed in g++

Tags: c++, boost, static, linker

I encountered a problem in using boost library.
When I build a sample code via g++, the link failed with the output **'ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64'**

The things I tried to solve the problem are as follows.

build boost with './b2 install address-model=64'

copy libraries to stage './b2 install stage'

copy libraries in 'stage/lib' to '/usr/lib'

Now there's a library named '/usr/lib/libboost_log.a'.

compile sample code with **'g++ sample.cpp -I /User/boost_1_57_0 -lboost_log'**

```
// sample.cpp
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
int main () {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    return 0;
}
```

I'd appreciate some help.

The full error message I got from is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::auto_release::~auto_release() in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::~record_pump() in log.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::push_record_unlocked(boost::rv<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record>&) in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level) in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()", referenced from:
      _main in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in log.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I resolved the problem by defining **-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK** in compile option.
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Due to the restriction to the length of comment, I posted some more error message here. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in log.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compo:.....ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The issue might be related to the version "v2s_mt_posix" while your .so may be using "v2_mt_posix" (you can check with `nm -CD /path/to/libboost_log.so`).

Comment: I edited my question with the full error message.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html (IMHO a bad design)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-L` to specify library path:

```
 -L /User/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib # or anything else
```

Comment: I already tried it. However the result was same as well. I just copied libraries under '/User/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib/*' to '/user/lib' to skip specifying '-L' option.